# Flutter - When to use mounted with setState()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand that according to the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

In what condition I need to use `setState()` with `mounted`? and when i shouldn't? Given 2 example below:

```
onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
    valueOld = value
 });
},
```

```
if(mounted){
   setState(() {
    valueOld = value
 });
}
```

Can someone guide me? Much appreciated! thank you:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mounted` property is `true` when briefly the object `State` associated `BuildContext` has been created and `initState` has been called.

This why if you want to use `setState((){ if(mounted) // TODO})` before `initState` you have to test if `State` is `mounted` to make sur that there is `Context` (State) already created.

In other case, you can use `setState((){ // TODO})` without `mounted` because the object `State` is mounted once.